# translate vs transform-origin css3

Tags: css, transform

I was wondering if someone could help me. I've been having trouble understanding what exactly is the css3 property: `transform-origin`. I can't seem to follow the direction it is moving.

So for example, lets say you have a square div, and you rotate it 40 degrees. and then you perform a `transform-origin: 100% 0%`. can't you just do a `translateX(and some value)`? It seems like translateX will move it along the x-axis with respect to the newly rotated axis after performing a rotate. I can't seem to follow what transform-origin is doing, or what exactly it even is.

A clear and thorough example would be much appreciated. =)

Comment: Some examples here: https://medium.com/hexacta-engineering/tune-your-css-transform-origin-and-rotation-visually-b043a8b1a03e

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`transform-origin` changes the point at which the element transforms rather than moving the entire element (as translate would). The default value is `transform-origin: 50% 50%;`.

Here is an illustration: http://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/73g7t/

Comment: @lack : In the ".wrapper div" definition contains the transition values and these values apply to all the boxes(blue,red and green). But the transform rotate in ".wrapper div" does not apply to the other boxes. For the other boxes transform rotate is mention separately in "wrapper .translate" and ".wrapper .transform-origin". Why is that?

Comment: @joshnh : This is referring to the fiddle provided by Lack. In the ".wrapper div" definition contains the transition values and these values apply to all the boxes(blue,red and green). But the transform rotate in ".wrapper div" does not apply to the other boxes. For the other boxes transform rotate is mention separately in "wrapper .translate" and ".wrapper .transform-origin". Why is that?

Comment: @Ashwin As the values have changed, they have to be declared separately.