# css3 where is the point of reference rotate() uses?

Tags: css, rotation, translate-animation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [translate vs transform-origin css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627939/translate-vs-transform-origin-css3)

I've been stuck trying to figure out how this rotate function works.

I have a div that I call a `rotate()` and `translate()` on. Then when I hover over the image, I perform one more `rotate()`. On the 2nd rotate, I can't seem to find the point of reference or what it revolves around.

The code is very simple but its really stumping me.

```css
div {
  height: 361px;
  width: 361px;
  background: rgba(119, 0, 36, 0.5);
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out 0.6s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.6s;
}
div#div2 {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(56.5deg) translateX(-180px);
  -moz-transform: rotate(56.5deg) translateX(-180px);
}
div#div2:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(56.5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(56.5deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div>Hello. This is a DIV element.</div>
  <div id="div2">Hello. This is a DIV element.</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Basically the grey block is rotated and has a translation on it. when you hover over it, I call another rotate(). but how is it rotating in a straight line?! it's crazy! I changed the values around for the `rotate()` in the hover and it still makes no sense to me.

Clear and thorough help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use [transform-origin](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-2d-transforms/#transform-origin-property), Luke.

Comment: I already answered this for you here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627939/translate-vs-transform-origin-css3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**rotate(angle)** does not append angle to rotation, but rotates the element to **angle**. So in ":hover" css, you have to give like

```
rotate(156.5deg);
```

Instead of translating, you can use **transform-origin** property in css.

hope this is what you want to achieve : http://jsfiddle.net/diode/QGE7F/9/

Comment: thanks a lot! that line you wrote...."rotate(angle) does not append angle to rotation, but rotates the element to angle" made all the difference in understanding haha. thanks! i thought it was the former way at first haha